# Createjs Loading issue in android 4.0 Devices

Tags: createjs

CreateJs assets are not loading in android version 4.0 default browser. Is there is support compatibility issue with android 4.0 version to load assets.

Comment: What kind of assets?

Answer (score 0):

sometimes mobile devices require a click event to load resources, so that is where I would start.

good luck and hope that helps.